# Are static vars in a method body shared by all instances

Tags: c++

```
class MyClass
{
public:
 void method2()
 {
  static int i;
  ...
 }
};
```

Will every instance of `MyClass` share one value `i`, or will each instance have its own copy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`static`, here, operates as in any regular function.

Which means that `i` is `static` within `MyClass::method2`, so there is one and only one instance of it.

Having one instance of a variable per object is what instance variables are for.

Answer (score 7):

Every instance of `MyClass` will share one value `i`.